# OUTER JOIN equivalent in MySQL

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I have two tables in MySQL Database with a representation of a clustering of people. The Tables `c_orig` and `c_now` map a `person_id` to a `cluster` number, like this:

```
person_id    cluster
    0           0
    1           0
    2           1
   ...         ...
```

I now want to know how many people changed cluster (where they came from or where they went to) when comparing `c_now` with `c_orig`. I can select the influx and outflux with the following two queries.

```
SET @CLUSTER = 0;

SELECT c_orig.cluster, COUNT(c_now.person_id) AS influx
FROM c_now
LEFT JOIN c_orig ON c_orig.person_id = c_now.person_id
WHERE c_now.cluster = @CLUSTER
AND (c_orig.cluster != @CLUSTER OR c_orig.cluster IS NULL)
GROUP BY c_orig.cluster;

SELECT c_now.cluster, COUNT(c_now.person_id) AS outflux
FROM c_now
LEFT JOIN c_orig ON c_orig.person_id = c_now.person_id
WHERE c_orig.cluster = @CLUSTER
AND c_now.cluster != @CLUSTER
GROUP BY c_now.cluster;
```

Results of these queries:

```
cluster  influx
  NULL     39
   1        8
   2        5
   3        2
   4        16
   6        9
   7        2
   8        1

cluster  outflux
   1        9
   2        7
   3       46
   4        5
   6       13
   7        2
   8        1
   9        5
```

Now I want to combine these queries, and have an influx/outflux of 0 when that cluster is not present in the query. However, I cannot `OUTER JOIN` them, and two `LEFT JOIN`s with different order seems too cumbersome. I guess I am overlooking an easy way to accomplish that. Can anyone help me out? Desired output:

```
cluster  influx   outflux
  NULL     39         0
   1        8         9
   2        5         7
   3        2        46
   4       16         5
   6        9        13
   7        2         2
   8        1         1
   9        0         5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `left join`, but you need a full list of clusters.  Given your queries, you can get it as:

```
(select cluster from c_now union
 select cluster from c_orig
) c
```

You would generate your query as:

```
select c.cluster, coalesce(q1.influx, 0) as influx, coalesce(q2.outflux, 0) as outflux
from (select cluster from c_now union
      select cluster from c_orig
     ) c left join
     (query1) q1 left join
     on c.cluster = q1.cluster
     (query2)
     on c.cluster = q2.cluster;
```

I am leaving out the details of your queries so you can see the overall structure of the query.  Just substitute your queries for `query1` and `query2`.

Comment: I had to change the first `LEFT JOIN` into a `RIGHT JOIN` to also get the `NULL` value in the output, but then it works. Thanks! :-)

Comment: On second thoughts: I guess it only worked in my real example, because I had no row only in outflux and not in influx, but with the current query, would such a row also be in the output?

Comment: @physicalattraction . . . Yes.  All the clusters in both tables would be in the output, because they are in the `c` subquery.